# renewcommand not working after using jmlr2e

Tags: environments, abstract, journal

I am using the [`jmlr2e.sty`](http://www.jmlr.org/format/jmlr2e.sty) package, used for papers submitted to a scientific journal. That sty file has the command `\renewenvironment` for redefining the `\begin{abstract}` command. Some lines below the `usepackage{jmlr2e}` I  write `\renewcommand\abstractname{newname}` but it doesn't work.
I have also tried `\AtBeginDocument` but the pdf keeps showing "Abstract" instead of "newname".

I am using Mac OS and Tex Live.

Comment: 'Not working' is not  a  precise description... Is `\abstractname` defined at all? If it is not defined, then `\renewcommand\abstractname` would fail, of course. Please post a document that shows this issue and give a link to this `jmlr2e.sty` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jmlr2e`](http://www.jmlr.org/format/jmlr2e.sty) doesn't use `\abstractname`. Instead, it hard-codes the name:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                               A B S T R A C T
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% use \begin{abstract} .. \end{abstract} for abstracts.
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\centerline{\large\bf Abstract}\vspace{0.7ex}%
  \bgroup\leftskip 20pt\rightskip 20pt\small\noindent\ignorespaces}%
{\par\egroup\vskip 0.25ex}
```

You can patch it with [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://www.jmlr.org/format/jmlr2e.sty
\usepackage{jmlr2e,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{Abstract}{newname}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```